# Why is the pdf toolbar not getting hidden using itextsharp?

Tags: pdf, itext

I used the below code to hide the toolbar widget that gets displayed in the browser.

```
stamper.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.HideToolbar);
```

When I open any pdf in the iframe it is still showing me that tooblbar widget. Is there any other way to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html), you are probably confusing the regular toolbar with the Heads Up Display (HUD):

[image: Heads Up Display]

This is not the toolbar that is referred to when you use `HideToolbar`.

What you're looking for isn't possible.
Read [the answer by Leonard Rosenthol](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/60287) (Adobe's PDF architect) on the iText mailing list, where he says:
*"there is no way to hide the toolbar (or the HUD) in the browser."*

Setting the tool bar to false works for the tool bar, but you are referring to the "Heads Up Display" (HUD).
Since version X of Adobe Reader, there is a new mode called "Read Mode",
which is the default viewing mode when you open a PDF in a web browser.
In "Read Mode" you can find a semi-transparent floating toolbar containing
basic reading controls, such as page navigation, print and zoom: the HUD.

As documented by Adobe, there is no way to customize this feature, let me [quote Adobe](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/what-developers-need-to-know-about-acrobat-x):

> the "Heads Up Display" (HUD) is not customizable. There are no APIs to
>   HUD. You can’t use JavaScript to enter Read Mode, exit Read Mode or
>   detect that the document is in Read Mode. Though it might seem like
>   it, this wasn’t an oversight. There are some very sound engineering
>   reasons why this is the case but I won’t go into those here.

Summarized: you're asking something that isn't supported in Adobe Acrobat / Reader.
Unchecking "Display in Read Mode by Default" can be done from *Edit > Preferences > Internet*
in Adobe Reader X but it there is no way to disable "read mode" programmatically.